# Java HTML Browser Error

Tags: java, jeditorpane

I created a simple JEditorPane browser that I want to retrieve data from, but first I need to log into a site. I have this currently:

[image]

But whenever I put in my credentials it just refreshes the page. If I put in wrong credentials, it does the same, showing no error. Am I missing something here?

Comment: Please include the relevant part of your code to understand your problem.

Comment: @LutzHorn I'm not sure what part of my code is relevant to understand. I just have a JEditorPane showing a webpage. If I press a button on that page, it just refreshes. I never modified anything or did anything to change what buttons on webpages do.

Comment: Then post everything on pastebin or similar site and then post the link here.